# Rails | Undefined method `constantize' for nil:NilClass | Access Method in other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey Stackoverflow community (first time asking for help, searched a lot, found nothing specific for my problem, links appreciated).

---

I have the following structure:
Employees and Comments.
The Employee has this in its model:

```
has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
```

The Comment has this in its model:

```
 belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
```

---

I have a "show.html" view in the "Employee MVC". In this view I want to show an input textfield to add a comment to an employee. This is not working.

If I click submit, I get an undefined method `constantize' for nil:NilClass Error. ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usKy9.png))

(On a seperate "new.html" in the "Comment MVC", I can create comments perfectly fine and add them to an employee).

**Code:**

*show.html.slim for the Employee*

```
h1
  | Mitarbeiter
  i<> = @employee.name

p Was für ein wundervoller Name!

hr

h2 Kommentare: 
- @employee.comments.each do |comms|
  p => comms.text

hr
**
= simple_form_for Comment.new do |f|
  = f.input :text, label: "Neuer Kommentar: "
  = f.hidden_field :commentable_id, value: @employee.id
  = f.hidden_field :commentable_type, value: @employee.class
  = f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary'**


a.btn.btn-success href=edit_employee_path(@employee)
  | Bearbeiten
p
a.btn.btn-warning href=employees_path Zurück
```

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /comments or /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1 or /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    klaz_name = params[:commentable_type]
    thing_id = params[:commentable_id]

    @thing = klaz_name.constantize.find(thing_id)
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments or /comments.json
  def create
    klaz_name = params[:commentable_type]
    thing_id = params[:commentable_id]

    @thing = klaz_name.constantize.find(thing_id)

    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params.merge(commentable: @thing))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to comment_url(@comment), notice: "Comment was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1 or /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to comment_url(@comment), notice: "Comment was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1 or /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: "Comment was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
    end
end
```

I tried to do it with a link_to and remote: true, but this didnt help either :/

Comment: Inspect the `params` object inside the controller action. The attributes you're looking for are likely nested under `comment` (eg `params.require(:comment).permit(:commentable_id, :commentable_type)`).

Comment: Still, might I suggest that you change your approach a bit. In practice you shouldn't have a `commentable_type` as part of the form. Firstly, it presents a security vulnerability. It allows a malicious user to `constantize` any string and `find` by id on any table. Secondly, it doesn't make that much sense UX-wise. For example, when I'm commenting on something I should be seeing what I'm commenting on. Therefore it's inconvenient if when I click "Comment" I'm redirected to a blank form page to write it just so that the "generic" comment action can be reused.

Comment: @ndnenkov thanks! This and the change in the input form to:
  `= hidden_field_tag :commentable_id, @employee.id`
did the trick :)
Works now.
And yes I am aware of the security risks, will change that later :)

Comment: This line is your problem: `= simple_form_for Comment.new do |f|`. Try changing to `= simple_form_for @employee.comments.new do |f|`.